# How to connect to CloudBees CI with JenkinsMobi

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

I have been trying a workflow on my smartphone where I would like to manually trigger a build with CloudBees.

I thought of trying to use JenkinsMobi, but I am stuck because I can not figure out the right configuration for connecting and I did not see it documented anywhere.

Hints welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to set this up pretty easily with a cloudbees Jenkins instance:

1. Click on the configuration icon in lower left hand of splash screen
2. Touch the "plus" button in upper right hand corner
3. Enter a description. For the host, enter the full hostname such as myacct.ci.cloudbees.com
4. Check HTTP/S checkbox
5. In security settings, enter my cloudbees username and password. This is the email address you used to sign up for CloudBees.
6. Test configuration 3-4 times till I got it to pass all the checks. I can't ever type my password correctly on these mobile keyboards
7. Press the "back" button, and click yes when prompted to save.
8. Touch the instance I created, and see the list of jobs.

In essence, it's like using JenkinsMobi against any other Jenkins instance.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works now. I did not change much, but there was a cap-sized sign in the URL, and for some reason that did not work, then.

Just to add the information to complete what I wanted to do: You can start a new build by going into your apps "Build info", and then tapping the Apps Settings button. From there it is "Start this build".